# Using javascript and php together

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP form that needs some very simple validation on submit. I'd rather do the validation client-side, as there's quite a bit of server-side validation that happens to deal with writing form values to a database. So I just want to call a javascript function onsubmit to compare values in two password fields. This is what I've got:

```
function validate(form){
  var password = form.password.value;
  var password2 = form.password2.value;
  alert("password:"+password+" password2:" + password2);

  if (password != password2) {
    alert("not equal");
    document.getElementByID("passwordError").style.display="inline";
    return false;
  }
  alert("equal");
  return true;
}
```

The idea being that a default-hidden div containing an error message would be displayed if the two passwords don't match. The alerts are just to display the values of password and password2, and then again to indicate whether they match or not (will not be used in production code).

I'm using an input type=submit button, and calling the function in the form tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
```

Everything is alerting as expected when entering non-matching values. I would have hoped (and assumed, based on past use) that if the function returned false, the actual submit would not occur. And yet, it is. I'm testing by entering non-matching values in the password fields, and the alerts clearly show me the values and the not equal result, but the actual form action is still occurring and it's trying to write to my database.

I'm pretty new at PHP; is there something about it that will not let me combine with javascript this way? Would it be better to use an input type=button and include submit() in the function itself if it returns true?

Comment: I don't see how far PHP is involved in this. It is a JS only problem.

Comment: No one's mentioned this yet, but keep in mind that you MUST perform validation in both client-side (JS) and server-side (PHP). Otherwise anyone could turn off their JavaScript and potentially insert invalid information into your database. #1 rule of web development, don't trust anything coming from the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an error in JavaScript occurs, the return false is not reached and the form will be submitted anyway.

And there is an error in your javascript: `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`.

Comment: +1 good catch. I've been staring at this for the last five minutes and failing to see the problem.

Comment: Also, you should never relly on javascript for validating your data..Yes, you should use javascript to help the user not to commit mistakes, but you should make the same verification on the server side, since javascript can be turned off, changed etc...
If you need to validate some more fields, i suggest you to search for some libraries for that porpuse like:
http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation
and
http://www.jsvalidate.com/

Comment: Thank you! Firebug didn't catch that, and I wouldn't have either. I've used that line of code in several other functions in the same js file, and have been staring at it for quite a while now trying to figure out what was different. I guess I was looking at it for too long; fresh eyes will always catch those.

Comment: @Gonçalo Queirós - in general I agree, but in this case I'm working in a controlled environment where I can be absolutely sure that the end users cannot turn javascript off.

Answer (score 0):

use a javascript library like prototype and a method like Event.stop() :

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/stop

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not get into libraries for a single validation on one page of a tiny site. Seems like swatting a fly with a Cadillac.

Comment: prototype is small and it does this kind of stuff well. when you're using a library, you are programming against a well-defined API, if not, you are programming against many different APIs (one for each browser), you are bound to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the method actually returns false. If there is an error before the return false statement, such as on this line

```
 document.getElementByID("passwordError").style.display="inline";
```

then the form may still submit.

Comment: The strange thing is, Firebug wasn't throwing any errors. I know now  that there is a typo (should be Id, not ID), but the error-trapper didn't catch it.